# Why is VC++ Compiler using boost\range\iterator.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, iterator, std

I appear to have an odd problem where my project is failing to compile. From what I can see it appears to be a problem with namespace where I wish to use `std::iterator`. However, looking at the errors, they appear to originate from its boost counterpart. I am not using `using's`, I am including the correct files, however some file names for stl & boost come under the same name. I'm unsure if that's causing some ambiguity.

The only boost file I am using in this instance is `/algorithm/string.hpp`

Below is the only code within the `.cpp` file using an iterator

```
std::map <ObjIndex, unsigned int> normalModelIndexMap;
std::map <unsigned int, unsigned int> indexMap;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < indexCount; i++)
{
    ObjIndex* currIndex = &ObjIndices[i];

    unsigned int iNormalModelIndex, iResultModelIndex, iPrevVertexLocation;

    vec3 currPos = vertexList[currIndex->index_Vertex];
    vec2 currTxrPos = vec2(0, 0);
    vec3 currNormal = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    if (hasUVs)
        currTxrPos = uvList[currIndex->index_UV];

    if (hasNormals)
        currNormal = normalsList[currIndex->index_Normal];

    std::map<ObjIndex, unsigned int>::iterator it = normalModelIndexMap.find(*currIndex);
```

And on build here is the Output log.

> *ObjLoader.cpp 1>f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69): error C2039:
>   'type' : is not a member of
>   'boost::mpl::eval_if_c,boost::range_mutable_iterator>'
>   1>          f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\value_type.hpp(26) :
>   see reference to class template instantiation
>   'boost::range_iterator' being compiled 1>          with 1>
>
>   [ 1>              T=char 1>          ] 1>
>
>   f:\gl_projects\opengl_engine\opengl_engine\opengl_engine\source\engine\util\objloader.cpp(197)
>   : see reference to class template instantiation
>   'boost::range_value' being compiled
>   1>f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69): error C2146:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
>   1>f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69): error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int 1>f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69):
>   error C2602: 'boost::range_iterator::type' is not a member of
>   a base class of 'boost::range_iterator' 1>          with 1>
>
>   [ 1>              T=char 1>          ] 1>
>
>   f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69) : see
>   declaration of 'boost::range_iterator::type' 1>          with
>   1>          [ 1>              T=char 1>          ]
>   1>f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69): error C2868:
>   'boost::range_iterator::type' : illegal syntax for
>   using-declaration; expected qualified-name 1>          with 1>
>
>   [ 1>              T=char 1>          ] 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error
>   C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' 1> 
>   f:\dev\boost\boost_1_57_0\boost\iterator\iterator_traits.hpp(22) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::iterator_traits' being compiled 1>          with 1>
>
>   ..........
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========*

It's likely I'm being negligent / doing something stupid. However, any help on offer to speed things along would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you downvoting?

Comment: Always debug by looking at the cause of the first error you see.

This is the offending line. What's there? `f:\gl_projects\opengl_engine\opengl_engine\opengl_engine\source\engine\util\objloader.cpp(197)`

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu: I imagine it's because of the lack of a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have posted the code for objloader.cpp. Theres only once instance of an iterator in the file and it's created at the bottom of the code block posted. There is no error for the class file however. The problem appears to start at iterator.hpp which for some reason is a boost file.

Comment: @AndrewMcCallum Clashing of include search pathes perhaps? Do you have any boost stuff in this project?

Comment: Sounds like your include paths are boned, out of order, or both.

Comment: I've checked the include paths. They appear to be set up correctly. I honestly don't know how I could screw it up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, though I found the issue. It was actually embarrassingly unrelated to includes, and the iterator in `objloader.cpp`.  I found that the issue was with boost::split() where I had passed in a char 'c' as opposed to a string element "c"....